# Entrando com uma expressão aritmética ao invés de um inteiro em C

Tags: c, io

Sou novo em C e fiz um programinha bem simples que recebe dois números e imprime a soma dos mesmos:

```c
// Programa que faz uma soma simples
#include <stdio.h>

// Função principal do programa
int main( void )
{
    int num1, num2, soma;

    printf("Entre com o primeiro número\n"); // Exibe texto na tela
    scanf("%d", &num1); // Lẽ o valor e o atribui a num1

    printf("Entre com o segundo número\n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    soma = num1 + num2;

    printf("A soma é %d\n", soma);
} // fim da função main
```

Compilei com o gcc e funcionou normalmente, mas por curiosidade eu resolvi fazer alguns experimentos. Quando o programa solicitava uma entrada, ao invés de digitar um valor inteiro eu coloquei uma expressão aritmética e para minha surpresa não é que funcionou? Quando eu entro com uma soma ou subtração na primeira entrada ele não solicita uma segunda entrada e imprime o resultado da operação:

```
$./soma
Entre com o primeiro número
8+10
Entre com o segundo número
A soma é 18
```

Quando eu entro com uma expressão aritmética no segundo scanf, o programa soma o valor da primeira entrada com o primeiro número da expressão, ignorando o restante:

```bsh
$./soma
Entre com o primeiro número
5
Entre com o segundo número
2+9
A soma é 7
```

O estranho acontece quando eu tento entrar com uma expressão envolvendo multiplicação ou um número de ponto flutuante, nesse caso o programa simplesmente devolve um valor aleatório:

```bsh
$./soma
Entre com o primeiro número
3*2
Entre com o segundo número
A soma é 1714397539

$./soma
Entre com o primeiro número
3*2
Entre com o segundo número
A soma é 98186483

$./soma
Entre com o primeiro número
3.4
Entre com o segundo número
A soma é 229452083
```

Minha pergunta é: Por que esse resultado estranho quando há multiplicação envolvida?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ao invés de digitar um valor inteiro eu coloquei uma expressão aritmética e para minha surpresa não é que funcionou?

**Dar o resultado que você espera é bem diferente de funcionar**. No caso foi mera coincidência como rapidamente se apercebeu quando fez uma multiplicação.

O pormenor que lhe está a escapar é que tanto `2` como `+2` como `-2` são números validos. Logo quando mete a entrada como `2+3` o primeiro numero será o `2` e o segundo numero é o `+3` que é apenas o `3` com sinal positivo.

Outra forma de confirmar isto é colocar a expressão `3-2`.

[Veja no ideone como colocando `3-2` na entrada obtem o resultado `1`](https://ideone.com/COOppx)

Não seria estranho se está a fazer uma soma no código, o resultado ter sido o da subtração ? E isso não tem a ver com o facto de interpretar uma expressão mas sim, de como são atribuídos os valores em `num1` e `num2`.

Neste caso o primeiro numero foi o `3` e o segundo numero lido foi `-2`.

[Neste ideone coloquei o print do segundo numero para que consiga perceber melhor](https://ideone.com/OpURSY)

Quando coloca um `*` o primeiro número é valido, mas o segundo já não é valido pois começa com um caratere inválido e por isso nada é lido para o `num2`. Como nada é colocado em `num2` ele fica com o valor que tinha, quer seja `0` ou um número aleatório na memoria, que já depende da implementação.

No [teste que fiz no ideone para `3*2`](https://ideone.com/1WOZKZ) o resultado sai apenas o valor do primeiro numero.

Assim como o @zentrunix disse, na duvida pode e deve confirmar quantos valores foram lidos corretamente através do retorno do `scanf`. No caso de `3*2` o `scanf("%d", &num2)` vai lhe devolver `0` pois não conseguiu ler nenhum numero, e ai já percebe que algo não funcionou corretamente.

Comment: complementando a resposta, o correto é sempre verificar o valor de retorno de scanf para saber o número da campos efetivamente lidos

Comment: @zentrunix Sim correto, e obrigado pelo complemento :)

Comment: Ainda estou um pouco intrigado sobre essa questão da multiplicação, acho que tem alguma coisa a ver com o ponteiro e tal. Espero que descubra estudando mais sobre C. Nessa IDE online eu consegui simular o resultado da multiplicação, embora aqui sempre dê um resultado próximo de 2¹⁵, enquanto no meu computador resulta em valores bem diferentes:  http://tpcg.io/vaFfFG

Comment: @Israel77 Não tem a ver com o ponteiro e sim com utilizar valores que não foram inicializados. Seria equivalente a fazer `int x; printf("%d", x);` em que você não consegue dizer qual o valor que vai mostrar e normalmente será um valor aleatorio que é o valor que esta no local de memoria onde a variavel foi alocada. O valor aleatorio normalmente é alto porque para ser baixo precisava de ter muitos bits a 0, quase todos os primeiros bits e isso é estatisticamente improvavel, ainda que possivel